# Synchronise local WebSQL/IndexedDB database with 'pre-built' database file?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, mozilla, web-sql, indexeddb

Is there any plan to make it possible to download (or synchronise from) a 'pre-built' database file, so to speak, for use with a local web browser database like WebSQL or IndexedDB?

At the moment, to add or update a local database it's necessary to export or store data in a format such as XML or JSON, then get, parse and store the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am under the impression that what you're looking for would be too much over-standardization on the browser side. As I understand it, IndexedDB is meant to be simple and robust enough for anyone to write JavaScript code that does the synchronization to your database server of choice.

In the meantime, you might take a look at these projects:

- [PouchDB](https://github.com/mikeal/pouchdb) - An implementation of CouchDB on top of IndexedDB. One of the premises is to offer the same synchronization (master-to-master) decentralized capabilities of CouchDB on the browser.
- [BrowserCouch](http://hg.toolness.com/browser-couch/raw-file/blog-post/index.html) - A similar project but using WebSQL as browser storage.